# Stack Overflow complains that my code is improperly formatted

Tags: support, code-formatting, quality-filter

I am trying to post a question about R, but Stack Overflow blocks the post with an error message about the code being improperly formatted. I have used Ctrl-k on the code and it is all highlighted in blue in the preview. How can I get around this?

[image: Post screenshot]

Comment: Can't see all of your post, but I have a feeling that the `[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE...` is probably what it is complaining about

Comment: You can use ctrl + k?? all this time i spent hitting the spacebar...

Comment: Guys seriously, this is a very new user, who is honestly asking for help on meta. There is barely anything to disagree with here, no need to DV.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stop focusing on your code that is already formatted as code.  The message is telling you that you have code that is not formatted as code.

Seeing as you appear to have formatted your obvious code as code (at least based 
on your screenshot), I would focus on the non-obvious stuff.

The first thing I would look at is the info you appear to be providing (see my freehand red circle below)

> [image]

This is very likely what is preventing you from asking the question.  You basically just have a series of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values with a few separators mixed in.  For the low quality filter, it probably looks like code, so it is blocking you from posting the question.

Depending what the info actually is supposed to represent would dictate how I would suggest you handle it.

- if it is not helpful to answering your question, then delete it.
- if it is input (or expected output) and you were trying to format it as a table, then you need to find a better solution.  Stack Overflow does not support any table formatting.  To actually format input or output data in a table, you should look at [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)
- if it is something else, then you may want to explain it more and possibly format the data as code or as a quote (ctrl+q).

Comment: Administering Ctrl-k on the TRUE FALSE output solved it.